# Jquery method not disabling buttons

Tags: jquery, disabled-control, prop

I am trying to disable buttons via a JQuery method. It should work by adding attributes and classes to them but it is not working.

I checked that I am sending the correct ID and I am not getting any errors in console but the button is not being disabled.

```css
$('[id^="pro2-consult"]').on("click", function (event, xhr, settings) {
  var id=event.target.id.substring(12);
  DisableBTNforConsult(id);
});

 function DisableBTNforConsult(id) {
  var cont1='#pro-save'+id;
  var cont2='#pro-create'+id;
  $(cont1, cont2).prop('disabled', true);
  $(cont1, cont2).addClass('btn-disabled');
  $(cont1, cont2).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
}
```

```html
<button id="pro-save-p-sis-0610" class=" btn btn-sm btn-success" type="button">Save</button>
<button id="pro-create-p-sis-0610" class=" btn btn-sm btn-success" type="button">Create</button>
<button id="pro2-consult-p-sis-0610" class=" btn btn-sm btn-success" type="button">consult</button>
```

Comment: How are you binding the method you posted to the buttons click event?

Comment: Also, where is your `#pro-create...` element?

Comment: i set and update with all the code ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Based on code from [the original version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/37286845/6) of the question, your `id` is coming up as `"p-sis-0610"`.  Then when you append it to `"#pro-save"` and `"#pro-create"`, you are missing a dash `-` in between.

   ```
   var cont1 = '#pro-save-' + id;
   var cont2 = '#pro-create-' + id;
   ```
2. Construct the jQuery selector as a single variable.

   ```
   var selector = cont1 + ', ' + cont2;
   ```

**Working DEMO:  https://jsfiddle.net/ob8taw48/**

---

You could also use jQuery's `$(this)` to get your `id`.

```
var id = $(this).attr('id').substring(12);
```

Comment: no id=event.target.id.substring(12); return me this value= -p-sis-0610

Comment: @WalterNuñez, not in my browser console.  In any case, my item #2 is the root cause.

Comment: the button fire the function is it: pro2-consult-p-sis-0610

Comment: @WalterNuñez, **[because you just changed it a few seconds ago!](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/37286845/7)**

Comment: yea my mistake but this work with the construction selector you make

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('button[id^=pro2-consult]').on("click", function() {
  var id=$(this).prop('id').substring(12);
  DisableBTNforConsult(id);
});

 function DisableBTNforConsult(id) {
  $('button:not(#pro2-consult'+id).prop('disabled', true);
  $('button:not(#pro2-consult'+id).addClass('btn-disabled');
  $('button:not(#pro2-consult'+id).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
}
```

```css
.btn-disabled{color:#eeddcc;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="pro-save-p-sis-0610" class=" btn btn-sm btn-success" type="button">Save</button>
<button id="pro-create-p-sis-0610" class=" btn btn-sm btn-success" type="button">Create</button>
<button id="pro2-consult-p-sis-0610" class=" btn btn-sm btn-success" type="button">consult</button>
```